# Combine four foreach into one foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to add 4 foreach into one. I know how to add 2 foreach into one like this :

```
foreach (array_combine($images, $covers) as $image => $cover) {
```

But i want to add more two foreach `$titles as $title` and `$albums as $album`.
I am not sure want like this :

```
foreach (array_combine($images, $covers) as $image => $cover) {
 foreach (array_combine($titles, $albums) as $title => $album) {
                               echo "$image-$cover-$title-$album"
```

It show me duplicate of every output.I mean output is

`demo-demo1-demo2-demo3demo-demo1-demo2-demo3`

Need output only

`demo-demo1-demo2-demo3`

Comment: Are you doing the same task on all the items? Could you add a little more information on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you are just trying to avoid writing duplicate code I would advice putting that code in a function and passing the needed arrays into it.

Comment: I am not sure and trying like this `foreach (array_combine($images, $covers) as $image => $cover) { foreach (array_combine($titles, $albums) as $title => $album) {`

Comment: Your not sure? Well take a look at your code and when you know what your trying to accomplish come back to me.

Comment: See updated question. @CalebB

Answer (score 1):

Put the for each statement in a function. Then create a loop that calls it.

```
public function loopMe($images, $covers)
{
   foreach (array_combine($images, $covers) as $image => $cover) { 
      $this->loopMe($image,$cover); 
   }
}
```

It looks like your second for loop is being called multiple times per item in the first for loop. So you want to make sure that you are only calling the second for loop once per image cover. or set an index cap on the second for loop. For instance if you are tyring to map the first item in the first for loop to the first item in the second for loop you should use an index.

```
public function loopMe($images)
{

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) { 
      echo $images[$i] . '-'. $title[$i] . '-' . $cover[$i] . '-'. $album[$i];
   }
}
```

Comment: @RobertW.GreeneJr. Sorry man! Your answer isn't complete, recursive function needs a break point, stopping condition, otherwise this will get an error.

Comment: wouldn't work anyways, since `$image` will be a key, not an array, and can't be used in array_combine()

Comment: whoever downv oted me sucks. you know im just trying to help out. wtf.

Comment: @ThiagoAugustusOliveira you don't even know what it was in reference too. he updated his question and considering he had minimal info at the time, my answer was appropriate. Don't just go in and down vote... contribute.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching this problem from the wrong angle. From what I can tell, you are trying to output the properties of something. I think what you want to do is approach this from an object-oriented approach by creating a class and using a method to output the contents of your object.

Something like this:

```
class MyAlbumThing {
    protected $image;
    protected $cover;
    protected $title;
    protected $album;

    public __construct($image, $cover, $title, $album) {
        $this->image = $image;
        $this->cover = $cover;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->album = $album;
    }

    public getImage() {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public getCover() {
        return $this->cover;
    }

    public getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public getAlbum() {
        return $this->album;
    }

    public getString() {
        return $this->image . '-' . 
            $this->cover . '-' . 
            $this->title . '-' . 
            $this->album;
    }
}
```

Then, you can instantiate this class and print your properties:

```
MyAlbumThing album = new MyAlbumThing("demo", "demo1", "demo2", "demo3");
echo $album->getString();
```

Would output:

```
demo-demo1-demo2-demo3
```

Also, if you hav a lot of these things, *then* you would use a foreach, like so:

```
$myAlbumArray = new array();
$myAlbumArray[] = new MyAlbumThing("demo", "demo1", "demo2", "demo3");
$myAlbumArray[] = new MyAlbumThing("anotherdemo", "anotherdemo1", "anotherdemo2", "anotherdemo3");

$lengthOfArray = sizeof(myAlbumArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $lengthOfArray; $i++) {
    echo $myAlbumArray[$i]->getString();
}
```

Sorry for any errors in my syntax, I wrote that in the browser without the help of my IDE.

I highly recommend learning more about object-oriented PHP programming. I found this article especially helpful while I was learning: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762

**EDIT**:
Please mark this answer as correct if you did indeed find this helpful for your problem.